# MSVC fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals with FFMPEG libs

Tags: visual-studio, ffmpeg, cmake

I am trying to utilize the ffmpeg libraries in a program of my own and am having trouble linking them. Specifically, In my a basic program I am receiving `fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals` errors. The program is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <libswresample/swresample.h>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
    struct SwrContext* swr_ctx = swr_alloc();
    if (!swr_ctx) {
        std::cout << "Could not allocate resampler context";
    }
}
```

I downloaded prebuild libraries from https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/, specifically the Windows x64 dev package which includes the .def/.lib as well as .dll files.

I originally tried (and intend to ultimately use) cmake to generate the MSVC sln files. The cmake file is:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(ffmpeg_jni)

# Find the JNI bits
find_package(JNI)

# Search for the ffmpeg libraries
set(ffmpeg_include_hint "ffmpeg-dev/include")
set(ffmpeg_lib_hint "ffmpeg-dev/lib")

find_path(SWRESAMPLE_INCLUDE_DIR libswresample/swresample.h PATHS ${ffmpeg_include_hint})
find_library(SWRESAMPLE_LIBRARY swresample PATHS ${ffmpeg_lib_hint})
add_library(swresample SHARED IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(swresample PROPERTIES
    IMPORTED_LOCATION "${SWRESAMPLE_LIBRARY}"
    IMPORTED_IMPLIB "${SWRESAMPLE_LIBRARY}"
    INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES "${SWRESAMPLE_INCLUDE_DIR}"
)

# Setup basic include dirs
set(includeDIRS
        src/main/cpp
        ${JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH})

# Setup windows specific includes
set(includeDIRS
        ${includeDIRS}
        ${JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH}/Win32)

include_directories(${includeDIRS})

set(WRAPPER_SRC
        src/main/cpp/logging.c
        src/main/cpp/logging.h
        src/main/cpp/main.cpp)

add_library(ffmpeg_jni SHARED ${WRAPPER_SRC})
target_link_libraries(ffmpeg_jni PRIVATE swresample)
```

The generated solution compiles and has proper access to the include files (Visual Studio can even take me to the declarations). The issue comes in the linking phase of the build where I receive:

> error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "struct SwrContext * __cdecl
>   swr_alloc(void)" (?swr_alloc@@YAPEAUSwrContext@@XZ) referenced in
>   function main

Thinking that I perhaps had something wrong in cmake since I am still pretty new with it I tried making a simple demo as a pure visual studio project following what I have found in countless online demos for adding an external library to a project. Specifically this included:

- Adding the directory containing the header files to Properties->C/C++->General->Additional Include Directories
- Adding the directory containing the .lib files to Properties->Linker->General->Additional Library Directories (Note that the cmake path did not do this but instead added the lib file via a relative path)
- Adding the .lib file to Properties->Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies

At this point any searching efforts I undertake show me different people doing the same things which tells me I've been looking at this too long to find the answer myself and its something trivial that I'm missing/not understanding.

Comment: @Vencat Thankyou, that resolved the issue. I knew it was something simple. I would be happy to accept it as an answer if you would like to move the comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are compiling your project as c++, then include FFmpeg headers as below which tells your c++ compiler to handle FFmpeg headers as C instead of C++.

```
extern "C" {
#include <libswresample/swresample.h>
}
```