# How to use ffmpeg in CMakeList?

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, cmake

I try to create CMakeList for using FFMPEG, but I have errors

CMakeList.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)
set(PROJECT_NAME Test)
project(${PROJECT_NAME})

message(STATUS "OS: ${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME}")

set(lib_type SHARED)

set(FFMPEG_INCLUDE "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/ffmpeg/include")

set(FFMPEG_LIB "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/ffmpeg/lib_win64")
set(FFMPEG_DLL "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/ffmpeg/dll_win64")

add_library(ffmpeg SHARED IMPORTED) # or STATIC instead of SHARED
set_target_properties(ffmpeg PROPERTIES
  IMPORTED_LOCATION "${FFMPEG_DLL}/avutil-56.dll"
  IMPORTED_IMPLIB "${FFMPEG_LIB}/avutil.lib"

  IMPORTED_LOCATION "${FFMPEG_DLL}/swresample-3.dll"
  IMPORTED_IMPLIB "${FFMPEG_LIB}/swresample.lib"

  IMPORTED_LOCATION "${FFMPEG_DLL}/swscale-5.dll"
  IMPORTED_IMPLIB "${FFMPEG_LIB}/swscale.lib"

  IMPORTED_LOCATION "${FFMPEG_DLL}/avcodec-58.dll"
  IMPORTED_IMPLIB "${FFMPEG_LIB}/avcodec.lib"

  IMPORTED_LOCATION "${FFMPEG_DLL}/avformat-58.dll"
  IMPORTED_IMPLIB "${FFMPEG_LIB}/avformat.lib"

  IMPORTED_LOCATION "${FFMPEG_DLL}/postproc-55.dll"
  IMPORTED_IMPLIB "${FFMPEG_LIB}/postproc.lib"

  IMPORTED_LOCATION "${FFMPEG_DLL}/avfilter-7.dll"
  IMPORTED_IMPLIB "${FFMPEG_LIB}/avfilter.lib"

  INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES "${FFMPEG_INCLUDE}/"
)

# Add source to this project's executable.
add_executable (${PROJECT_NAME} "Test.cpp" "Test.h")

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ffmpeg)

install (TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME} DESTINATION bin)
```

Test.cpp

```
#include "Test.h"
#include <libavutil/avutil.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //uint32_t res = av_float2int(1.0f);
    auto res = av_d2q(24.654, 2);   
    cout << "Hello CMake." << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

if I call `av_float2int` - it works, but returns trash.

if I call `av_d2q`, I get error:

> Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol  "struct AVRational __cdecl
> av_d2q(double,int)" (?av_d2q@@YA?AUAVRational@@NH@Z) referenced in
> function main

Where is the mistake?

UPD 1.

I added `extern "C" {}`. Error remained

> Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol av_d2q referenced in function
> main

UPD 2.

I removed lines from `set_target_properties`

Now so CMakeList:

```
set(FFMPEG_INCLUDE "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/ffmpeg/include")

set(FFMPEG_LIB "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/ffmpeg/lib_win64")
set(FFMPEG_DLL "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/ffmpeg/dll_win64")

add_library(avutil SHARED IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(avutil PROPERTIES
  IMPORTED_LOCATION "${FFMPEG_DLL}/avutil-56.dll"
  IMPORTED_IMPLIB "${FFMPEG_LIB}/avutil.lib"

  INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES "${FFMPEG_INCLUDE}/"
)

# Add source to this project's executable.
add_executable (${PROJECT_NAME} "Test.cpp" "Test.h")

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE avutil)
```

But I have erorr

> not found avutil-56.dll

I think I should copy dlls to exe path

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/a/57526839/10334333

Comment: @Vencat, yes. I think about extern C

Comment: @Vencat, It did not help

Comment: I think problem with `set_target_properties` where I added a lot of options

Comment: av_d2q declared here  libavutil/rational.h